# Problem mining Genesis Block in Dash Clone

Tags: altcoin, genesis-block, dash

Good morning, I need help !! I have cloned other coins (scrypt and SHA256), but I found a big problem with the DASH CLONE.
After having completed the DASHCLONE project. When I can not do the genesis block (tried with QT and tried with daemon) it does not mine .........! getgenerate = true, but do not mine!
the log writes this:

CMasternodeSync::ProcessTick -- nTick 1189 nRequestedMasternodeAssets 0 nRequestedMasternodeAttempt 0 nSyncProgress -0.250000

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION!!!!!!

for mining 1 block is necessary to change functions inside chainparams.cpp

[image]

RESULT:

[image]

**BOOM!!!!!!!!!!!!**

if you want a genesisblock calculator inside your project whatch this my repository:

https://gist.github.com/anewstarslot/a86a65d890ed823013315ea2d3727c2d

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with dash-coin, however, in my experience with cloning other coins (litecoin w/ scrypt PoW, bitcoin w/ SHA256) even with a few nodes running the client, I was unable to mine with an external mining software (like cpuminer) until 15-20th block was generated using the CLI. Either within the qt client console or using the coin-cli generate nblocks command.

If you have successfully coded the genesis block into the source and were able to compile/run the client I would try using the generate command or whatever the equivalent is within the client.

Comment: ho già ammassato il litecoin e generato i primi blocchi con comando cli generate 1 (per esempio). Unfortunately with Dash, when you enter: setgenerate true, the response is: getgenerate true, but really do not mining

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, yeah I have had that same issue. I believe the setgenerate config option is deprecated, so you have to use the cli generate nblocks or use mining software like cpuminer/gpuminer/cgminer etc.

Comment: yes, it's deprecated. but you can not even use generate nblocks because it is disabled.
if you change the variable fMineBlocksOnDemand = true, you can use the generate nblocks command, but the qt or the daemon crash.
You can not use ccminer, cgminer etc., because the wallet is not synchronized to the network.

That is the question..

Comment: How many nodes do you have running the client..?

Comment: only 2 nodes... but in scrypt i havent problems with one node too

Comment: My recommendation would be to add more nodes, or to start over and ensure you maintain at least a single node with the entire blockchain. As long as you do that and maintain consensus across your other nodes, synchronization should be automatic.

Comment: I tried to do that too. I created the coin clone from the Dash. I tried to put 3 knots in sync with each other. unfortunately nothing. it does not mine

Comment: Doesn't mine with the generate command? or an external miner? What command specifically are you using. You normally can't mine blocks that will be accepted by an external miner until the coinbase height is at least around 20, and depending on your hardware you may need to be patient while the generate command works.

Comment: generate = 1 is deprecated, it does not work in Dash.

          setgenerate = true => tells me that it is undermining, but actually after a week it has not generated any blocking and the CPU memory is at zero ... so it does not undermine.

          gen = 1 in the file .log => tells me that it is undermining, but after a week it did not generate any blocking and the CPU memory is at zero ... so it does not undermine

          external miners (miners only) => do not work until the wallet is synchronized on the network, so it must first generate the 1st block

Comment: try using whatevercoin-cli generate 1 99999999, your right, external miners won't work without synchronization but you should be able to generate a block from within the core regardless, so long as the core runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: MAIN: PART 1]

[image: MAIN: PART 2]

[image: MAIN: PART 3]

[image: MAIN: PART 4]

[image: MAIN: PART 5]

[image: MAIN: PART 6]

All Modify are signed //Mod.

NOT MINING REALLY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

[image]

not mining!!!

All modifies are in test and testreg too.